# Renaming multiple files in bash by removing prefix and suffix containing special characters %?=

Tags: bash, sed, rename, mv

I recently make a request against the Google Cloud Service API endpoint and wget a lot of files into one single folder. Owing to the fact that all sub-directories separator `0/` are being replaced by `%2F` with the addition of `?alt=media`, all the downloaded files are contaminated with these strings. e.g.

```
hg38%2Fv0%2FHomo_sapiens_assembly38.dict?alt=media
hg19%2Fv0%2FHomo_sapiens_assembly19.fasta.alt?alt=media
```

I tried to test the following in bash and it returned the result i wanted:

```
echo "$hg19%2Fv0%2FHomo_sapiens_assembly19.fasta.alt?alt=media" | sed -e "s/^$hg19%2Fv0%2F//" -e "s/\?.*//g"
```

i.e. Homo_sapiens_assembly19.fasta.alt.  Unfortunately when I scaled it up using,

```
for file in *; do 
    mv "$file" '$(echo "$file" | sed -e "s/^$hg19%2Fv0%2F//" -e "s/\?.*//g")' ; 
done
```

all the files turned into 1 file named "$file". I couldnt figure out why.

Please can anyone provide a solution to my problem? And if some of the files contain different repeats of "%2F", how can I elegantly only keep the string after the last "%2F" and string the "?alt=media" from the end in the same line?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have the `rename` command? It can do this without writing a script.

Comment: `$()` is not expanded inside single quotes, only double quotes.

Comment: It shouldn't have renamed them to `$file`, it should have renamed them to `$(echo "$file" | sed -e "s/^$hg19%2Fv0%2F//" -e "s/\?.*//g")`

Comment: I don't see how your initial test could have worked. It will try to use a variable named `$hg19`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Why do you have `$` before `hg19`?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I am trying to submit a pbs script.

Comment: I thought $ is necessary.

Comment: so should i swap the single and double quote around?

Comment: I posted an answer several minutes ago showing how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.*` to match everything up to the last `%2F`.

Put the command substitution inside double quotes, not single quotes. See [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Don't put `$` before `hg` at the beginning.

It's not a requirement, but `sed` commands are usually put in single quotes, unless you're using variables in the substitution.

```
for file in *; do 
    mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed -e 's/^hg.*%2F//' -e 's/\?.*//g')" ; 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

actually to removing all occurrences of `%2F` except for the last one, you can do like this:

```
echo "hg38%2Fv0%2FHomo_sapiens_assembly38.dict?alt=media" | sed -e "s/.*%2F\([^%]*\)\?alt.*/\1/"
```

- ".*%2F" matches any characters followed by the last occurrence of "%2F".
- "([^%]*)" captures any characters that are not "%".
- "?alt.*" matches the string "?alt" followed by any characters.

result is :

```
Homo_sapiens_assembly38.dict
```

and about the `for` loop something like this :

```
for file in *
 do mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed -e "s/^$hg19%2Fv0%2F//" -e "s/\?.*//g")"
done
```

Comment: Thank youuu for providing an answer to my question. Appreciate it!!!